# Is there a way to use snowflake-connector-python library in aws lambda for running unit tests?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that connects to snowflake. I have written some unit test. to execute those unit tests snowflake-connector-python library is needed. Unfortunately, when I add snowflake-connector-python in my reequipments.txt the package size increases and returns error - Unzipped size must be smaller than 119273261 bytes.

Is there a way to install this particular library somewhere else and use during unit test execution?

Unit test doesn't uses layer so adding this library in layers is not a solution, I guess.

I tried adding library in requrements.txt file and it increase lambda package size beyond the limit.

Comment: I'd try using docker to install all of your packages and use the dockerized lambda function. You can build everything locally without that memory constraint and clean up the image to keep the runtime small